# How can I view the default and available search engines in Chrome programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome

I wrote a program similar to HiJackThis to show all of Chromes extensions, plugins and homepages, but cannot find where Chrome stores it's default search engine and the list of available search engines. Anybody know which file this is stored in? Thank You.

Comment: I found the default search provider at the beginning of the preference file. This is mainly what I needed, but if anyone knows where the list of available search providers are, that would be quite useful.

Comment: NOTE: If Google is your default, it will now show any default info. But if it is something else like Yahoo, then all the info is displayed. This is why I could not find it on my computer until I set Yahoo as my default and then it showed up in the preference file